# How to split a returned integer: (Trying to find recurrences within it)

Tags: python

This might be a very simple question, but it's giving me a lot of trouble.

Code:

```
def search_likes(passed_list): #passed_list contains links to find below
    print("Found",len(passed_list),"videos, now finding likes.")
    x = 0
    print("Currently fidning likes for video",x,".")
    while x< len(passed_list): 
        likeFINDER = []
        r = requests.get(passed_list[0])
        soup= BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
        d_data = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "yt-uix-button-content"}) #Location of the number i'm looking for
        likeFINDER.append(d_data)
        str1= ''.join(str(e) for e in likeFINDER) #Converts the list into a string
        likeNUMBER= (int(''.join(list(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), str1))))) #Removes string and leaves integers


        x+=1 #count
```

Output:

845528455314391440

I would like to split the code where it begins to repeat itself. Ie ['84552','8455314391440']

If you have any insight on how to do this I would really appreciate it!

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: But it does not fully repeat itself...

Comment: I understand that. I'm looking to split it where it BEGINS to repeat itself

Comment: and how do you define *begins* to repeat itself? The first character?

Comment: What are the parameters for length of repetition? Single digit, two digits, three? is there a minimum length?

Comment: Sorry about that. Three should be enough

Comment: Assuming you have a set number of digits from the front that you are using to define repeating numbers. Like in this case it looks like it would be 5 digits. Then you can use regular expression to match the first 5 digits or any other amount.

Comment: I wish. The numbers will never be the same, but the repetition pattern will always exist. ie ['1234','123335']  *for the first few digits

Comment: Is your answer just about an algorithm that takes a number and splits it like that? If so, it seems like you should be able to reduce the amount of code that you included by quite a bit. The `BeautifulSoup` stuff doesn't seem directly related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a string `s` containing your numbers, and a number `n` that is the size of the repetition you want to find, then you can do:

```
s.find(s[:n], n)
```

This finds the index of the first occurrence, after the start of the string, that is equal to the first `n` characters of the string. For example:

```
s = str(845528455314391440)
n = 3
r = s.find(s[:n], n)
print(r)
```

Output:

```
5
```

You can then use that to split the string and turn the parts into numbers:

```
a, b = int(s[:r]), int(s[r:])
print(a, b)
```

Output:

```
84552 8455314391440
```

All combined into a function, accounting for numbers without repitition:

```
def split_repeat(i, n):
    s = str(i)
    r = s.find(s[:n], n)
    if r == -1:
        return None
    else:
        return int(s[:r]), int(s[r:])
```

Usage:

```
print(split_repeat(845528455314391440, 3))
print(split_repeat(876543210, 3))
print(split_repeat(1122, 3))
```

Output:

```
(84552, 8455314391440)
None
None
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: Instead of thanking in comments, be sure to [upvote and accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the best answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example that will show yo how you can match the numbers of how ever many of the first few digits  you need to. This example will use the first 2 digits.

we can turn the numbers into strings then use `string_name[:2]` where 2 is the number of digits from the front you want to match. I am using the number 11 to match my list of numbers but this is only for an example.

Let me know if you have any question:

```
set_list = []
var1 = 11012314

for i in range(1000):
    set_list.append(i)

for item in set_list:
    x = str(item)
    y = str(var1)
    if x[:2] == y[:2]:

        print(item)
```

When you run this code you will see numbers printed to the console that match the first two digits to our variable with the value 11.

Answer (score 0):

you can do :

```
def myfunc(num):
    a=str(num)
    for i in range(len(a)):
         l1=a[:i]
         l2=a[i:]
         if l1 in l2:
                 b=l1
    return [int(b), int(a[len(b):])]
```

that will give you :

```
>>> myfunc(845538455314391440)
[84553, 8455314391440]
```